# Estimation of $\sum_{n\leq x}|\mu (n)|* \mu$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Let $\mu$ be te Moebius function.
The question is: Use the Riemann hypotesis to prove that $\sum_{n\leq x}|\mu (n)|* \mu<<_{\epsilon}x^{\frac{1}{4}+\epsilon}$
I know that the drichelet series of $|\mu|$ is $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta (2s)}$ but i don't know how to use this. I can't find information about $\frac{1}{\zeta (2s)}$.
Any suggestion please?

Comment: I only know that RH implies that the function of lindelof in the critical line has value $0$, and don't know what is $\sum_{n\leq x}n^{-s}(|\mu|*\mu (n)$ but the entire drichelet series is $\frac{1}{\zeta (2s)}$.

Comment: Thus $\sum_{n \le x}|\mu |* \mu(n) = ?$. Your knowledge of Tauberian theorems is useful mainly for estimating $\sum_{n \le x} \mu(n)$ under the RH

Comment: Sorry, i don't know waht is a Tauberian theorem, can you give me some reference please? And for what you say about estimating $\mu$, i understand.. and than i use the hyperbole method?

Comment: Tauberian theorem : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353948/riemanns-method-for-asymptotic-formulas

Comment: Thanks you, perfect i don't know the name. But i need a bound for $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ near $1/2$ right?

Comment: Sure, see Titchmarsh the last chapter "consequence of the RH" or equivalent, usually it starts with $\zeta'/\zeta(s)= o(\log |\Im(s)|)$ then it shows the same result for $\log \zeta(s)$ obtaining (under the RH) $1/\zeta(s) =O( |\Im(s)|^{\epsilon})$ on $\Re(s) \ge \sigma> 1/2$